# Dropdown links outside the navbar and it's items not centered

Tags: css

I'm trying to do a navigation bar but not all the links stay at the same level, the drop down menu ones stay outside the navigation bar div and I can't align them.

Also, the container that has the drop down menu links isn't centered right bellow the drop down link.
I don't know how I can center it.

```
.topnav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    background-color: #333;
}

.topnav a {
    color: #f2f2f2;
    padding: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
}

.topnav a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
    color: black;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: #f1f1f1
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
```

```
<div class="topnav">

    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Example link</a>

    <div class="dropdown">
        <a href="#">Dropdown menu 1</a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="#">Link 2</a>
            <a href="#">An example link</a>
            <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="dropdown">
        <a href="#">Dropdown menu 2</a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="#">Link 4</a>
            <a href="#">Link 5</a>
            <a href="#">An example link 2</a>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this:

```
.dropdown a {
  display:flex;
}
```

and your item element with a drop down should get aligned in the same space.

#### Update 1

You might need to set a fixed width on the submenu in order to keep it centred, like the following:

```
.dropdown-content {
    left: -80px;
    margin-left: 50%;
}
```

```css
.topnav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    background-color: #333;
}

.topnav a {
    color: #f2f2f2;
    padding: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
}

.topnav a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
    color: black;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown a {
  display:flex;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    left: -80px; /* 160px/2 */
    margin-left: 50%; /* 50% */

}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: #f1f1f1
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav">

    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Example link</a>

    <div class="dropdown">
        <a href="#">Dropdown menu 1</a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="#">Link 2</a>
            <a href="#">An example link</a>
            <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="dropdown">
        <a href="#">Dropdown menu 2</a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="#">Link 4</a>
            <a href="#">Link 5</a>
            <a href="#">An example link 2</a>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: The items in the navbar are correct but I still need the container with the links of the dropdown menu, in this case the divs with the three links to be centered right bellow the dorpdown link.

Answer (score 0):

**Just Add This Code In** -> `.topNav`

```
align-items: center;
```